# How to upload multiple images one by one through html?

Tags: html, css

With the below code, I was able to upload to multiple files at a time.But, if I want to add one by one then the previous uploaded image is overridden with the new one. Please help me in resolving this.

```
<form action="post" class="login-form">

<div>
    <label class="left cell">Summary:</label>
    <div class="cell">
        <input class="right" type="text" name="Summary" style="width:400px">
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <label class="left cell">Description:</label>
    <div class="cell">
        <textarea class="right" name="Description" style="height:100px;width:400px"></textarea>
   </div>
</div>

<div>
    <label class="left cell">Price:</label>
    <div class="cell">
        <input class="right" type="text" name="Price" style="width:300px">
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <label class="left cell">Upload Photos:</label>
    <div class="cell">
        <input class="right" type="file" id="images" multiple>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the server side programming being used? I believe you'll have to handle this issue from server side.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402187/multiple-files-upload-and-using-file-reader-to-preview)?